# Old versions of the reference genome and dbSNP

Tags: database, public-databases, variant-calling, reference-genome

For benchmark purposes I’m trying to find an old version of the human reference genome (pre-GRCh37) and a matching version of dbSNP.

Unfortunately it appears as though older versions of dbSNP aren’t archived, or at least these archives are not publicly accessible.

In particular, [the NCBI FTP archive](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp/organisms/archive) is fairly sparse. The only pre-GRCh37 version it contains is ostensibly [dbSNP build 124 from January 2005](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/SNP/snp_summary.cgi?build_id=124), for hg17 (NCBI build 35). Unfortunately [the corresponding FTP folder is actually *empty*](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp/organisms/archive/human_9606_b124_NCBI35/). dbSNP build 138 has been “removed to recover storage”, whatever that means, and I’m unclear which version of the human reference genome it refers to (its [official page](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/SNP/snp_summary.cgi?build_id=138) does not contain this rather crucial bit of information).

Is there another authoritative source of this data?

Comment: Perhaps ENSEMBL will have some of what you need? At least the older reference genomes appear to be there. https://www.ensembl.org/info/data/ftp/index.html

Comment: @Scot Ensembl has variation data but it does not, as far as I know, host the dbSNP data (i.e. a dataset exactly corresponding to a given dbSNP build). Although I might be able to filter the corresponding entries from their variant database, and convert it to VCF.

Comment: Actually this won’t work: The NCBI36 variant data on Ensembl doesn’t contain dbSNP information directly, and it’s in a format that’s not trivial to convert to VCF.

Answer (score 2):

The UCSC Genome Browser downloads page has old human genome assembly versions way back to the first human genome ever published (by UCSC in 2000).
http://hgdownload.soe.ucsc.edu/downloads.html#human

We also have a variety of archived dbSNP data up to dbSNP141 on hg38, dbSNP 131 on hg37, dbSNP126 on hg18:
http://hgdownload.soe.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg38/database/snp141.txt.gz
http://hgdownload.soe.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg19/database/snp138.txt.gz
http://hgdownload.soe.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg18/database/snp126.txt.gz

They're in a custom table format, which can be turned into VCF manually.

You can also get all of this data from Table Browser and add filters, etc.:
http://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTables